# How many ways can this hexagon be tiled by 11 rhombuses of unit side length?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I came across a question in an exercise booklet for Mathematic Olympiad for primary school students in Australia. The question is shown in the following picture:
[image]
I barely have any clue how this sort of questions can be approached. Would anyone please help solve this question and possibly suggest a general solution, if any, to this kind of problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: How many rhombuses can be oriented vertically in this tiling?  Once you know that, how many ways are there of placing the vertical rhombuses?  As for a general approach, it seems that 22 equilateral triangles is a bit arbitrary.  Try to solve a simplified case like a regular hexagon (6 triangles), then increase the complexity to the case with 10 triangles, then 14.  Spotted the pattern?  Can you use induction to find the general case?

Comment: You can look up "tilings if 2 x n strip dominoes" with google, should be a good way to start such problems (_that_ problem results in Fibonacci numbers). @MichaelMay

Comment: Thank you, @DougM, for your helpful clues. I now understand how to look at this pattern.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyBurdin, for your recommendation. I'll check out the similar problem shortly. It may suggest some clues for a general approach to tackle the question presented in this post.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a single rhombus vertically, the rest of the rhombuses on either side **have to be placed horizontally**, otherwise there will be some "lonely" triangles that don't get covered. (Try putting the vertical rhombus on the far rightmost side first, and then fill in from there, to convince yourself of this). Also, **there has to be at least one vertical rhombus in the tiling**; placing all the rhombuses horizontally leaves "lonely" triangles again. So the number of possible tilings is equal to the number of places you can initially put the vertical rhombus, which in this case is 6.

Comment: "Try putting ... to convince yourself" misses rigor. The hint of seeng where the vertical rhombus is is already given in the comments.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Hints $\neq$ answers. I could add rigor if the OP wants me to, but the essential insight is there, and my answer is more direct than the hint given in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote our hexagon-like figures as $H(n)$, where $n$ is the horizontal length of it. In our case $n=6$.
Let's also denote number of tiling of such rhombus by $T(n)$.

See, that for $n>1$ we can start tiling in two ways:

1. By placing single rhombus vertically:

[image]

This option gives us only one way of evaluation - adding rhombuses 'horizontally':

[image]

2. By placing two rhombuses 'horizontally':

[image]

As we can see, by this action we've reached the figure $H(n-1)$

For $n=1$ it's obviously only one way of tiling.

Therefore we can describe the number of tilings using the following formula:
$$T(n) = \begin{cases}1, & n=1\\ T(n-1)+1 , & n>1\end{cases}$$

This is simply equivalent to the neutral function:
$$T(n)=n$$
Therefore in our case ($n=6$) the number of possible tilings is $6$